# Cómo modificar contactos con intents?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-intent, contact-form-7

tal vez alguien puedar echarme una mano, estoy tratando de guardar un contacto desde mi aplicacion, pero cuando se envian los datos no aparece bien el nombre del contacto. adjunto capturas.

Gracias de ante mano. c:

**Este es el fragento de codigo para guardar el contacto:**

```
 val addContact = Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION).apply {
        type = ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE

        putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME,
            resources.getString(R.string.app_name))

        putExtra(
            ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Nickname.NAME
        )

        putExtra(
            ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE,
            resources.getString(R.string.app_telephone_contact)
        )
    }

    startActivity(addContact)
```

**Este es el resultado en el emulador (tambien lo probé en un dispositivo fisico):**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: a qué te refieres con " cuando se envían los datos no aparece bien el nombre del contacto" ?

Comment: si te fijas en la captura el nombre del contacto que aprece ahi lo pone como "Data1" mientras que en el codigo yo le paso un String con el nombre de app, y no se porque no se guarda de esa manera, no se que estoy haciendo mal.